# xgettext > search through smarty templates for {php}{/php} tags

Tags: php, smarty, xgettext

How could I use xgettext with poedit to replace tags like these:

```
{php}printf(_("You have to pay &euro; %01.2f for this car."), $this->get_template_vars('amount')){/php}
```

I've renamed my tpl files to .tpl.php but in default form xgettext will only translate string within php tags. I know it should be possible with the parsercommand function in poedit but it lacks documentation on how to do so.

Comment: As workaround: let Smarty convert the templates, and feed xgettext the templates.c/*.php files.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that. But for this project it's hard to trigger each page to have it cached.